# App running in backgroung after "Process.Start". How to fix this?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .NetCore 3.0 Console application that is starting normally when clicked on "App.exe".
However, when I call it through "Process.Start("C:\App\App.exe ")", it is running in the background.
How to fix this?

```
private static void Init_App()
         {
            try
            {
                Process.Start("C:\\App\\App.exe");

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Err - " + e.Message);
            }
         }
```

Comment: It will run in background regardless. Do you want to hide UI of your app?

Comment: @eocron what do you mean it will run in the background? It is a separate executable not a thread.

Comment: What do mean by it runs in the background?

Comment: Is it actually closing pretty fast instead of running in the background?

Comment: Console Apps close if you dont add a Console.ReadLine at the end of the Main method.... But because Visual Studio has a setting for debugging they are kept open when debugging... So may what you need to do is add Console.ReadLine at the very end of your Main method in your App.exe console app that way when you start it from another app it will stay open

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what the problem is when you say it "runs in the background".

But if you want to run a separate process that keeps running even if you close the first app and that it is NOT a child of the first process....

Then you can do something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var info = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            UseShellExecute = true,
            FileName = @"C:\App\App.exe",//this app also needs a Console.ReadLine at the end of it's Main method.
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        };
        Process.Start(info);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Also remember that Console Applications close really fast if they exit the Main method.
So in your App.exe add a Console.ReadLine at the end of the Main method so that it actually stays open.  Otherwise it will close immediately.

When you debug visual studio keeps the console app running but that is just a setting under:

**Tools-> Debugging-> General -> Automatically close the console when debugging stops**

But when the app is deployed or called from another app it will close as soon as the Main method is done.

Comment: @MikailhP please mark as answered if this solved your problem.  Thank you.